# I need to access my 15.10 desktop with remote access. How can I do so?

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop

I have a Ubuntu 15.10 desktop that has some programs on it that I cannot get on my Ubuntu 14 laptop. However, I would like to be able to use these programs when I am away from home with my laptop. What way is the best to do so?

I have looked around and I have come across just a remote desktop client option, such as Teamviewer. Teamviewer, however, is slow. However, if there was a way to have a remote desktop just into the program I need to use, that would also be a possibility.

I have also seen options for servers, but I don't know if this would really help in my situation.

Comment: What's the program here you're referring to? Does it have a command-line-interface?

Comment: Matlab.  And that's how I run it is through command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/), which is a UI based remote desktop or you can look at [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) which is console based.

While VNC requires a serer to be installed on your desktop machine, PuTTY would use the ssh server running on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a graphical application without 3D acceleration and you need speed, the best way is to use X Display forwarding over SSH.

Please reference external manuals, such as:
http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html

Or a previous stackexchange question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

VNC protocol requires to much bandwidth, Teamviewer is proprietary software.